# Microsoft Graph API - Get subscriptions issue

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have tried to get subscriptions list
`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions`

And got the response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "QueryNotSupported",
        "message": "Get Subscriptions list is not supported for the API version 1.0.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "39473acc-179a-4a41-beba-0dd7887c299b",
            "date": "2019-09-17T07:49:12"
        }
    }
}
```

The same request is eventually working during the last couple of hours.
Are there some migration activities with Graph API?

Thank you

Update:
Subscriptions getting is working now, but when I got subscription's id

```
        {
            "id": "45f46028-2f93-4167-947a-2a1dda035226",
            "resource": "users/****/events",
            "applicationId": "***",
            "changeType": "created,updated,deleted",
            "clientState": null,
            "notificationUrl": "******",
            "expirationDateTime": "2019-09-19T19:46:53.934Z",
            "creatorId": "****"
        },
```

and tried to delete it:
`DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions/45f46028-2f93-4167-947a-2a1dda035226`
I got the response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ResourceNotFound",
        "message": "The object was not found.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "c485edd8-cc2e-461b-8c90-2cb5cc8dbebd",
            "date": "2019-09-19T08:51:46"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We are sorry, but we did have a degradation of service affecting those two operations (list and delete). It has been resolved since.